# AWS Loadbalancer is not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, amazon-elb

I have a solution (AnzoGraph DB) deployed on my AWS Kubernetes Cluster (EC2 Instance), and was working totally fine.
Suddenly this solution stopped and i could not access it via the DNS anymore.
I tested the solution deployed on my cluster using kubectl port-forward command and they are working fine (the pods and services), thus i assume the problem is with AWS Loadbalancer.

To access the application we need to go through this path:
Request -> DNS -> AWS Load Balancer -> Services -> Pods.

The LoadBalancer is (classic) internal, so it's only accessible for me or the company using VPN.
Every time when I try to access the DNS , I got no response.

Any idea how i can fix it ? or where is the exact issue ? how can I troubleshoot this issue and follow the traffic on AWS ?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: does your loadbalancer have healthy targets downstream when you check it in the AWS console?  This sounds like a security group issue.

Comment: How can i check exactly? (i'am a beginner)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-healthcheck.html

Answer (score 0):

sorry I missed your post earlier.

lets start with a few questions...
You say you use k8s on AWS EC2, do you actually use EKS, or do you run a different k8s stack?

Also ... you mentioned that you access the LB from your (DB) client/ your software by DNS resolving the LB and then access AnzoGraph DB.

I want to make sure that the solution is actually DNS resolving the LB via DNS every time. if you have a long running service, and AWS *changes* the IP address of the LB, and your SW possibly had cached the IP, you would not be able to connect to the LB.

- on the system you run your Software accessing AnzoGraph DB ... (I assume CentOS (7) )
- make sure you have dig installed (yum install bind-utils)
- dig {{ your DNS name of your LB }}
  is that actually the IP address your SW is accessing?
- has the IP address of the client changed? make sure the LB SG allows access
  (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-groups.html)

I assume you access the AnzoGraph DB frontend POD via 443?
as you write

> "I tested the solution deployed on my cluster using kubectl port-forward command and they are working fine (the pods and services)"

we probably do not have to look for pod logs.
(if that was not the case, the LB would obviously block traffic as well.)

So I agree, that the most likely issue is (bad) DNS caching or SG due to different SRC IP being rejected by the classic LB SG.

also for completeness .. please tell us more about your env.

- AnzoGraph DB image
- EKS/k8s version
- helm chart / AnzoGraph operator used.

Best - Frank